# disabling text on DataGridViewTextBoxColumn

Tags: .net, winforms

Is there a way I can disable non-numeric data in a DataGridViewTextBox column?

The field in my database is a float, and I want the user to only be able to input numeric values.

Answer (score 0):

I have not encountered this personally, but I know of a few ways. You could define your own column type to restrict this, or you could handle the DataGridView events.

Take a look here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wc5cbb9z.aspx

Specifically: `CellValidating` and `CellValueChanged`

Answer (score 0):

You can also try listening to the TextChanged event of the DataFridViewTextBox column's editing control and prevent the user from inputing invalid values into the textbox.
E.x.:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        string _prevValue;
        int _selLength;
        int _selStart;
        private bool _ignoreTxtChange;

        public Form1()
        {
            DataGridView dataGridView = new DataGridView();
            dataGridView.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
            Controls.Add(dataGridView);
            DataTable ds = new DataTable();
            ds.Columns.Add("FloatValue", typeof(float));
            dataGridView.DataSource = ds;
            dataGridView.EditingControlShowing += dataGridView_EditingControlShowing;
        }

        private void dataGridView_EditingControlShowing(object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
        {
            DataGridView dataGridView = (DataGridView)sender;
            TextBox textBox = e.Control as TextBox;
            if (textBox == null)
            {
                return;
            }
            textBox.TextChanged -= textBox_TextChanged;
            DataGridViewColumn floatColumn = dataGridView.Columns["FloatValue"];
            if (dataGridView.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex != floatColumn.Index)
            {
                return;
            }
            textBox.TextChanged += textBox_TextChanged;
            _prevValue = textBox.Text;
        }

        void textBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (_ignoreTxtChange)
            {
                return;
            }
            _ignoreTxtChange = true;
            TextBox textBox = (TextBox)sender;
            float value;
            if ((_prevValue == textBox.Text) || float.TryParse(textBox.Text, out value))
            {
                _prevValue = textBox.Text;
                _selLength = textBox.SelectionLength;
                _selStart = textBox.SelectionStart;
            }
            else
            {
                textBox.Text = _prevValue;
                textBox.Select((_selStart == 0) ? 0 : _selStart - 1, _selLength);
            }
            _ignoreTxtChange = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you think there would be a significant performance hit with this? If he were to handle the `CellValidating` event he could just `TryCast` the value to the desired type of the `ColumnIndex` matched the column he was looking for. This way events wouldn't be getting added / removed each time a user enters rows of the `TextBoxColumn`. Instead, it would perform one check when the user is done entering the data. It would probably also require less code and be easier to manage should additional columns need similar restrictions.

Comment: There won't be a significant performance hit. The main benefit of performing validation on the editing control is it prevents the invalid values from ever entering the cell.